I'm getting a JDBC driver error while creating an expense tracker
I'm creating an expense tracker using SQLite in Java, and after adding JDBC and SLF4J to the project classpath, I get this error;

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:expenses.db

I've confirmed that SLF4J and JDBC are in the classpath for the project.
Here's my code;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ExpensesTracker extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField expenseField, amountField;
    private JButton addButton, deleteButton;
    private JTable expenseTable;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private Connection connection;

    public ExpensesTracker() {
        setTitle("Expense Tracker");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        expenseField = new JTextField(20);
        amountField = new JTextField(10);
        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Expense:"));
        topPanel.add(expenseField);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Amount:"));
        topPanel.add(amountField);
        topPanel.add(addButton);
        topPanel.add(deleteButton);

        String[] columnNames = {"Expense", "Amount"};
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        expenseTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(expenseTable);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        deleteButton.addActionListener(this);

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:expenses.db");
            refreshTable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void refreshTable() {
        tableModel.setRowCount(0);
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM expenses");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String expense = resultSet.getString("expense");
                double amount = resultSet.getDouble("amount");
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{expense, amount});
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == addButton) {
            String expense = expenseField.getText();
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(amountField.getText());
            try {
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO expenses (expense, amount) VALUES (?, ?)");
                statement.setString(1, expense);
                statement.setDouble(2, amount);
                statement.executeUpdate();
                refreshTable();
                expenseField.setText("");
                amountField.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == deleteButton) {
            int selectedRow = expenseTable.getSelectedRow();
            if (selectedRow != -1) {
                String expense = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
                try {
                    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM expenses WHERE expense = ?");
                    statement.setString(1, expense);
                    statement.executeUpdate();
                    refreshTable();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ExpensesTracker().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?
I've also tried reverting to SLF4J version 1.7, as advised on github, and I still get the same error.

That presupposes a database file of the name expenses.db in the current directory
Is that the case? You need to close your statements in try-with-resources

JDBC is a framework, built into Java. You cannot add it to the classpath as you stated; JDBC is already automatically on the classpath. Do not confuse that for a JDBC Driver.

By the way, SQLite is a very limited database. You might want to consider alternatively, such as H2 Database Engine which is written in pure Java and comes with a JDBC Driver.

Tip: Learn about try-with-resources syntax to automatically close your Statement, ResultSet, etc. You can find complete SQL/JDBC app examples posted here on Stack Overflow if you search — some posted by me.

@BasilBourque nothing wrong with sqlite if one wants to use it as portable solution to store some relation data.

The error message “No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:expenses.db” indicates that your application is unable to find the appropriate JDBC driver for SQLite. To resolve this issue, you need to:

Download the JDBC Driver (you can get it from the official SQLite website or from Maven Central) Add driver to classpath in your Project
Check Your Connection URL The format for an SQLite connection URL is: jdbc:sqlite:sqlite_database_file_path , where sqlite_database_file_path is the actual path to your SQLite database file.

